# Identificar una anagrama

Tags: java, string, comparaciones

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio y necesito identificar un anagrama. Más o menos lo tengo, pero me falla, pues no identifico correctamente las mayúsculas de las minúsculas y esto no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo.

He definido un método para meter la palabra a analizar en un TreeMap y de este modo sé las letras de las palabra y el número de veces que contiene dicha letra, y así también lo tengo ordenado para poder comparar con otras palabras, pero me falla, pues añade cantidad independientemente de si la letra es mayúscula o minúscula.

El código es

```
    static TreeMap getTreemap(String a){
    TreeMap<Character, Integer> mapa = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0;i<a.length(); i++){
        Integer valor = mapa.get(a.charAt(i));
        if (valor != null){
            mapa.put(a.charAt(i), valor+1);
        }else{
            mapa.put(a.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }
    return mapa;

}
```

puede que mi problema venga a continuación, cuando comparo las palabras aquí.

```
        if (mapaA.equals(mapaB) != true){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

Ya que me dice que ambos son iguales, a pesar de que no coincidan may o minúsculas.
Alguna sugerencia para arreglarlo?
Gracias.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que estas comparando, ya que un anagrama puede ser la palabra  "AMOR" que también es "MORA"  pero todas mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Comment: Justamente, AMOR y MORA sí es un anagrama válido, pero no deberia ser igual si fuera Amor - MORA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes mirar esta alternativa

```
    public static boolean esAnagrama(String s1, String s2) {

        char[] array1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] array2 = s2.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(array1);
        Arrays.sort(array2);
        return new String(array1).equals(new String(array2));
    }
```

Comment: Pues si, creo que tambien es buena.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo he resuelto del siguiente modo.

En vez de trabajar con Character, he decidido pasar a String y de este modo poder usar la constante String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER. De este modo, sí diferencia entre may y minúsculas. No he encontrado como poder hacerlo con Chars, pero este modo me ha parecido bastante más elegante )obviando esto a.charAt(i)+"", claro).

El código queda así.

```
    static TreeMap getTreemap(String a){
    TreeMap<String, Integer> mapa = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    for (int i = 0;i<a.length(); i++){
        Integer valor = mapa.get(a.charAt(i)+"");
        if (valor != null){
            mapa.put(a.charAt(i)+"", valor+1);
        }else{
            mapa.put(a.charAt(i)+"", 1);
        }
    }
    return mapa;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```html
.compareTo()
```

en vez de

equals()